# Organizing shared layout and assets between several projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Every time I create a new Rails application, and for the admin part, I copy the layout and assets from another project to the new project.

I think it's obvious how many problems this approach causes. I am thinking about organizing my layout, and assets in a proper way.

What I have in mind is creating a gem and putting everything in that gem. But before I try that, I wonder if there is a better way for organizing these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem is good if you want to share codes among apps.

If, like your case, the shared parts have routes/views, an **engine** would be better suited, which is also a kind of gem. You can check the guide for details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: It does not have routes/views. It has only one layout file, and several stylesheets/images.

Comment: @Ako, if that is the case, for assets(styles/js/imgs) only, you can just create a very simple gem and don't need engine. For the only simple view, the layout, just copy it directly.